# play selected songs

Tags: asp.net

I have a reqiurement, I need to play multiple audio songson ASP.Net page.Can anyone suggest the best way to implement this.

I have page. There I will display the list of the songs in grid view. The gridview contains checkboxes and songs name. User should able to select the multiple check boxes and click play.

When ever user click play button on new popup window I have to play the all audio songs selected by user one by one.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Silverlight here, Silverlight would work really well for this feature.  Build a silverlight app that has a MediaElement control that plays audio and video.

HTH.